# Libgdx shader that affects whole screen

Tags: opengl, libgdx, shader

I'm making a game in Libgdx.

The only way I have ever known how to use shaders is to have the batch affect the given textures one after another. This is what I normally do in my code:

```
shader = new ShaderProgram(Gdx.files.internal("shaders/shader.vert"), Gdx.files.internal("shaders/shader.frag"));
batch.setShader(shader);
```

And that's about all of the needed code.

Anyways, I do not want this separation between textures. However, I can't find any way to affect the whole screen at once with a shader, like the whole screen is just one big texture. To me, it seems like the most logical way to use a shader.

So, does anyone know how to do something like this?

Comment: Draw all using one batch.

Comment: There are many different ways you can use shaders. With knowing specificly what you're trying to do, it's hard to answer. Are you doing a post processing effect that changes colors? Or makes things pixelated? Or modifies lighting, or does anti-aliasing?

Comment: For most kinds of full screen effects, you can draw everything into a frame buffer object normally, and then draw the FrameBuffer's texture to the screen with a special shader.

Answer (score 0):

Draw all textures (players, actors, landscape, ...) with the same batch and, if you want to affect also the background with the same shader, draw a still texture with the size of the screen in the background and draw it with the same batch.

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy with FBO objects, you can get "the whole screen as just one big texture" like you said in your question:

First of all, before any rendering, create yout FBO object and begin it:

```
FrameBuffer fbo = new FrameBuffer(Format.RGBA8888, Width, Height, false);
fbo.begin();
```

Then do all of your normal rendering:

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
...
Batch b = new SpriteBatach(...
//Whatever rendering code  you have
```

Finally save that FBO into a texture or sprite, do any transformation needed on it, and prepare and use your shader on it.

```
fbo.end();
SpriteBatch b = new SpriteBatch();
Sprite s = new Sprite(fbo.getColorBufferTexture());
s.flip(false,true); //Coord systems in buffer differs from screen

b.setShader(your_shader);
b.begin();

your_shader.setUniformMatrix("u_projTrans",camera.combined); //if you have camera
viewport.apply(); //if you have viewport
b.draw(s,0,0,viewportWidth,viewportHeight);  

b.end();
b.setShader(null);
```

And this is all!

Essentially what you are doing is to "render" all your assets and game scene and stages into a buffer, than, saving that buffer image into a texture and finally rendering that texture with the shader effect you want.

As you may notice, this is highly inefficient, since you are copying all your screen to a buffer. Also note that some older drivers only support power of 2 sizes for the FBO, so you may have to have that in mind, check [here](https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/FrameBufferObjects) for more information on the topic.